# talend (java) multiply an integer column by a bigdecimal column

Tags: java, talend

I need to multiply in talend an integer column by a bigdecimal column and I tried a few things but it doesn't work. Forgive me I don't really know Java but talend wants me to enter a java input for this operation in a tMap.

Here is what I'm looking at:
Column1, it is an integer and it's name is:
row2.quantityOrdered

Column2, it is a bigdecimal column and it's name is:
row2.priceUnit

I'm trying to do it in a tMap. I want to create a new column (row2.value) that is the multiplication of one column by the other.

I know I have to do multiply(BigDecimal something but I don't really know how to fill the rest of the command. If you could help it would be great!

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that row2.Var1 is int, row2.Var2 is BigDecimal and that value output field in the tMap is BigDecimal, you can use the following Java Code in the tMap Output Column:

```
row2.Var2.multiply(new BigDecimal(row2.Var1)
```